# how should i disappear submenu?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using a nav menu in my project.The menu has several menu which again has sub-menu and mega menu.when i click on a link which has a sub menu its items will appear and it will disappear when i click on another link(which has NOT submenu)
but my problem is : when i click on a link which has sub menu , a previous link's submenu will NOt disappear.so that finally all the links will stay open(showing their submenu) just by clicking on a single link they will disappear.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#right-menu > ul li').click(function(event) {
    if($(this).find('ul ').hasClass('active'))
    {
        $(this).find('ul').removeClass('active').slideUp('400');
    }else{
        $(this).find('ul').addClass('active').slideDown('400');
    }
});
});
```

Comment: please add your html code, your question will be more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your logic so that you check if the clicked element is active to start with. Then slide up any `ul` tag that is also active. Finally, only slide down if the clicked element was not active to start with.

Something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#right-menu > ul li').click(function(event) {
        var activeStart = false;

        if($(this).find('ul').hasClass('active'))
        {
            activeStart = true;
        }

        $('ul.active').removeClass('active').slideUp('400');

        if(!activeStart) {
            $(this).find('ul').addClass('active').slideDown('400');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is. If a user clicks on a link with sublinks the sublinks must slide down. And when clicking on another link the active sublinks must slide up and the clicked sublinks must slide down. You could try this.
Add a class `<ul class='non-active'>` to the link

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
$('#right-menu > ul li').click(function(event) {
   $('.non-active').slideUp('400');
$(this).find('ul').slideDown('400');
});
});
```